# missing option to move file to recycle bin

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, ntfs, recycle-bin

recently, i bought a seagate backup plus slim 2TB external HDD so that i could move my in-game recorded video before editing. i used a third party partition software to format my new drive to NTFS from exFAT and run a disk check for error. no error was found.

then, i remove and reconnected my drive and i was unable to access my drive. i asked others and they said it was due to security issue which i was able to solve. then i tried to copy some videos to my drive. no problem in copying files but there was no changes to drive size. i did a disk check to solve the incorrect drive size bitmap problem.

but now, i have a problem in file deletion where i can only delete my file permanently but there was no option to move to recycle bin. i checked my recycle bin properties. the "don't move file to recycle bin" option was unchecked.

[IMAGE - missing recycle bin option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/za1aR.png)

Answer (score 2):

First, if the drive is optimized for quick removal, as in USB flash drives, no *Recycle Bin* is shown. Check *Better performance*, and probably enable write caching, for an external HDD or SSD.

[image: Quick Removal dlg]

Second, very large files or files that added to existing trash would exceed the size set for the *Recycle Bin* cannot be recycled. Set the maximum size of the bin appropriately. Even so, Windows may warn you a file is too large for the bin.

[image: Size of Recycle Bin]

Third, as you mentioned, "Don't move files to the Recycle Bin..." should not be selected **for the external USB drive**. This setting is *per drive*.